# Iterating over a string in R

Tags: python, r, string

I was wandering if it is possible to iterate over an string in R as we can do it with pyhon:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

    myvector=[]
    for string in dataframe.columns: 
        myvector.append(int(string[:-2])) #deleting identifiers

    myvector = np.array(sorted(list(set(myvector))))
```

BR

Comment: Please add a reproducible example along with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `R`, we can substring in the column names, get the `unique` elements and `sort`

```
nm1 <- substr(names(dat), 1, nchar(names(dat))-2)
sort(unique(nm1))
```